# Android lost reference in onClick AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, reference, onclick, android-alertdialog

I've sent data in/out of dialogs before, but this has got me stumped on what the problem is.

The value of mylocalDataRef is lost, when the onClick method is called. The idea is to display just the name of a level, as the input for AlertDialog is String[] only. When the user clicks on a level, I use mylocalDataRef.get(item), to retrieve the full object and send that off to the activity.

When debugging, mylocalDataRef is not null, i.e. it doesn't crash when calling the get() method, however I cannot see its value (as if it was null), and the return result from get() is always null.

Can anyone shed light on what is happening.

p.s. showLevels() is called in onOptionsItemSelected(), that is when a user clicks on a menu button on the action bar.

```
   private void showLevels()
   {
        final ArrayList<Level> mylocalDataRef = levels;
        String[] simpleLevels = new String[mylocalDataRef.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < mylocalDataRef.size(); i++)
        {
            simpleLevels[i] = mylocalDataRef.get(i).getName();
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick a level");
        builder.setItems(mylocalDataRef, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LevelActivity.class);
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.putExtra("result", mylocalDataRef .get(item).getId());
                i.putExtra("levelname", mylocalDataRef .get(item).getName());
                i.putExtra("type", "level");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semi-resolved it.

The value of mylocalDataRef in onClick is not null, and does contain the correct data. The reason why I suspected a problem was the getExtras in the activity not getting the correct answers. This was down to using getStringExtra instead of getIntExtra.

Why the debugger, cannot see the value of mylocalDataRef is beyond me, it made it look like null. So I printed it out to the log console to prove the data was there.